# image from local memory does not load

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

Im working on a project where i get a link to an image from my DB.

This is the code which loads the image.

```
export const PostImage = styled.div`
  background-image: url(${props => (props.bgimg ? props.bgimg : singlePostBgImg)});
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
```

when i am using a link of this type it works perfectly:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/xxx.com/xxx-images/hotel-4_thumb.jpg
```

however, when i use a link to an image inside my own computer, no picture is displayed.

```
file:///C:/Users/Andre/Desktop/PFP/pssv.jpg
C:/Users/Andre/Desktop/PFP/pssv.jpg
```

when i use the Links in the browser they work perfectly. What did i wrong?

Comment: Does `file:///C:` tries to load in network tab? Maybe it's CORS that blocks access?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome/6083677#6083677) ..?

Comment: @Justinas Sorry for the late answer. i looked up and chrome prohibit the access. 
Errror
scroll-spy.js:40 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/Andre/Desktop/PFP/pssv.jpg

What should i do?

Comment: Put your resources under same folder as your index file. Otherwise it will not be loaded (offline CORS are even more strict).